# Does partial commit happen when TransactionInDoubtException is encountered?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, msdtc

Does partial commit happen when `TransactionInDoubtException` is encountered? If so how to roll back the commits/ properly handle `TransactionInDoubtException`

```
var option = new TransactionOptions();
option.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option))
{
    try
    {
         Context.SaveEmail(_emailInfoList);
         context.SaveSyncState(syncState);
         scope.Complete();
         return true;
    }
    catch (TransactionInDoubtException ex)
    {
         // Looks like commit has already taken place 
         // How to roll back the changes ??
         // sth like scope.Rollback()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionindoubtexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**:

> This exception is thrown when an action is attempted on a transaction
>   that is in doubt. A transaction is in doubt when the state of the
>   transaction cannot be determined. Specifically, **the final outcome of
>   the transaction, whether it commits or aborts, is never known for this
>   transaction.**
>
> This exception is also thrown when an attempt is made to commit the
>   transaction and the transaction becomes InDoubt.
>
> This is a recoverable error.

**EDIT:**

**For recovery:** 
You have to catch `TransactionInDoubtException`& write compensate logic with apt checks.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option))
    {
        try
        {
            Context.SaveEmail(_emailInfoList);
            context.SaveSyncState(syncState);
            scope.Complete();
            return true;
        }
        catch (TransactionInDoubtException ex)
        {
            //check whether any one record from the batch has been partially committed . If committed then no need to reprocess this batch.     

            // transaction scope should be disposed first .

            scope.Dispose();

            if (IsReprocessingNeeded(syncState))
                throw;

            return true;
        }
    }

        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool IsReprocessingNeeded(SyncStateDataModal syncState)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var id = _emailInfoList[0].ID;
                    bool isEmailsCommitted = Context.GetJournalEmail().FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id) != null;
                    if (!isEmailsCommitted)
                        return true;
                    if (context.EmailSynch(syncState.Id) == null)
                    {
                        context.SaveSyncState(syncState);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(AppConfiguration.RetryConnectionIntervalInMin));
                }
            }
        }
```

**SOURCE** [What is the recovery path for TransactionInDoubtException ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b88ca922-9939-410a-aaf6-7532f4ba9945/what-is-the-recovery-path-for-transactionindoubtexception-?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: What is the recovery path?

Comment: How does this provide answer to the question. Its better suites for comment rather than answer.